# Not able to skip row using skiprow in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hey guys I was just working on pandas, I imported the excel dataset and tried to select the header by skiping the first four row but it is not working could you guys help me to do that

here's my code

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("Practical example Descriptive statistics_exercise.xlsx", skiprow = 4)
df
```

[image]

here is what i have did but i want to add the header the one which is marked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need specify all rows for skipping in list:

```
df = pd.read_excel("Practical example Descriptive statistics_exercise.xlsx",
                   skiprows = [0,1,2,3])
```

Or specify which row is header:

```
df = pd.read_excel("Practical example Descriptive statistics_exercise.xlsx", header= 4)
```

Python counts from `0`, so for exclude first row is use `0` and for header in fifth row is used `4`.